# Selenium WebDriver - Chrome Brwoser opens, gets the URL and do not enter credentials on the Webpage.

Tags: selenium-webdriver

It throws org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: disconnected: unable to connect to renderer. 
Chromedriver version: 2.33
Chrome browser version: 62.0
Selenium WebDriver: 3.6.0

Comment: Try to run you code in lower version of Chrome browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same problem from this morning. As per previous answer updated chrome driver to 2.33 and resolved issue. Chromedriver download link:- https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.33

Answer (score 1):

According to the [release notes](http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.33/notes.txt) if you are using:

1. Selenium 3.6.0
2. chromedriver 2.33
3. Chrome browser 62

You shouldn't have problem. I'm using these and I haven't this issue. Make sure about these versions.